# Operator+ not returning what i expect c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
matrixType& matrixType::operator+(const matrixType& matrixRight)
{
    matrixType temp;
    if(rowSize == matrixRight.rowSize && columnSize == matrixRight.columnSize)
    {
        temp.setRowsColumns(rowSize, columnSize);
        for (int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<columnSize;j++)
            {   
                temp.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + matrixRight.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot add matricies that are different sizes." << endl;
    }
    cout << temp;
    return temp;
}
```

the cout at the end prints out what i would expect but when i add matrix a and matrix b together in my main there is no output i don't understand why it would be right on the line before i return it but it doesn't do anything when it returns.

```
int main()
{
    matrixType a(2,2);
    matrixType b(2,2);
    matrixType c;
    cout << "fill matrix a:"<< endl;;
    a.fillMatrix();
    cout << "fill matrix b:"<< endl;;
    b.fillMatrix();

    cout << a;
    cout << b;

    cout <<"matrix a + matrix b =" << a+b;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

the cout a prints out the matrix a correct and same for b but the a+b doesnt print anything although in the operator overload above i print it out and it prints out correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a temporary, leading to *undefined behaviour*. An `operator+` should return a value:

```
matrixType operator+(const matrixType& matrixRight);
```

Comment: While that's definitely correct, for matrix types this may get expensive if return value optimization is off or doesn't work. For this kind of heavy-weight data structures it might be a good idea to use other member functions or operator+=.

Comment: @arne I would expect NRVO to work, but it would help to make the types efficiently movable in the case where it doesn't. Still, there could be problems in expressions involving many temporaires, in which case some template expression magic is a good solution. I am not sure how one can gain from member functions or `operator+=` for expressions of the type `Matrix a = b + c;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, the last kind of expression doesn't do well with `operator+=`, but it can be written as `Matrix a = b; a += c`. I only see problems with massive amounts of temporaries, probably in complex equations involving multiplication, inversion etc, etc. You could easily write member functions like `add(Matrix const &summand, Matrix &result)` to avoid the copy.